# NodeJs :Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

Tags: node.js

I am working with nodejs.  Website was working fine previosuly .  We enabled https.

Now i made changes in code to send ajax request instead of http to https ..

When i check it on chrome. it gives me following error

**Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED**

But it is working fine in Firefox

Any reason

Comment: I never even changed any code, I am getting this error for https calls in Chrome, but they work fine in IE and Firefox....

Comment: Gavin, i am facing this issue too

Comment: Found the cause and solution. We changed the SSL certificate and something on the computer was holding onto the old one. After rebooting my computer the error went away on Chrome.

Comment: I had this issue and the solution was to update Nginx. I believe there was a newer implementation of SPDY available.